Radiated Emissions signatures
I have a question about the appearance of two Radiated Emissions graphs. Specifically, I want to understand why the curve looks thicker from 100MHz to 1GHz in one of the graphs.
I observed that the Resolution Bandwidth (RBW) is set to 100kHz for the thicker curve and 300kHz for the thinner one. Is this difference in RBW the reason for the variation in the curve's appearance? If so, can you explain why this happens?
I am not concerned with comparing the EMI signatures between the systems, but rather with understanding the impact of RBW on the appearance of the curves, if there is any.

Here is a graph where the signature appears much slimmer compared to the previous one.


Do you know the time per measurement?

The thinner curve, the lab has reported 15seconds and the thicker, I cannot guarantee what it is. @Jeroen3

You need to compare two graphs from the same source. I mean there's over 4 years between the two sets of results so they are not going to be similar even if the BW was the same.

Hi @Andy, as stated in the question, I do not really care about the signature of the systems...
The graphs are just for the sake of illustrating my point. They are by the way from the same source, it is the same unit being retested.
My question was more regarding the RBW and the effect it has on the curve.
anyway, I believe Tim Williams provided me with a very good answer.

For these "quasi peak" detection tests, the spectrum analyser is in "max hold" (record) so when there is a lot of variation in output power on a given frequency, the graph will naturally appear thicker there.

Yes, most likely.  RBW is like bin width for a DFT, but in continuous form.  Specifically, for the traditional swept analyzer at least -- what is read out is a signal over time, as the receiver sweeps across the frequency range given.  RBW acts as a filter kernel on this signal, and higher RBW means a wider range of frequencies (literally, more width on the screen) is received at any given time.
Obviously, for a DFT acquisition, the bins are literally wider, so the average (or RMS or QP) per bin will ignore the lowest peaks within that bin, and so it gets smoothed out.
It might also be a pointwise acquisition, where a zero-sweep receiver is held at each successive frequency in a sequence, and the detector simply does what it does.  (This is more common, I think, for proper EMI testing, especially QP mode.)  This again prioritizes higher amplitude peaks, filling in the valleys.
In any case, consider the likelihood of a given acquisition point or bin to have received little energy: it's far less likely to happen over a wider bandwidth, even simply for thermal noise.  If the signal is randomly distributed (but persistent and stable) peaks, the same argument applies.

So if I understand correctly with a wider RBW, it's less likely to encounter a measurement point with little energy. It must be because a larger bandwidth captures more signal and noise components? If so, even random noise will be more prominent with a wider RBW.
Essentially, with a higher RBW, the EMI appearance will likely be smoother and show higher average levels due to the wider frequency range being included in each measurement, which seems like it is the case.

Yes, indeed if you look at the reading of a spec. just with input disconnected or terminated, the baseline noise level varies with RBW. In this case, the noise is white, and the bandwidth and peak or average level are related by the power spectral density of that noise (resistance and temperature).

Perfect. Thank you very much for the clear explanation!

The fact that the graph is logarithmic also plays a role here.  The measurement bins remain at the same bandwidth throughout, but the graph compresses them together more and more the  further up in frequency you go.

Yes, there are more bins per pixel at the high end than low -- this explains the difference in "hair" within one plot, say below 100 or 70 MHz, versus above.
